# Replicate "Save as HTML complete" in Java Action

Tags: java, html

How can I replicate the `"Save as HTML, complete"` command in a Java action?

I need to save a webpage, but it has local references such as `"css/screen.css"` or `"images/logo.png"`.

If I manually save it with Firefox, for instance, I get a contents folders so that it all works.

Didn't find a way to do the same in Java, all I have is a code to download just the HTML source, but it still has local references.

Any tip?

```
 URL url = new URL("http://www.google.it");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
    (new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter
    (new FileWriter("data.html"));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       System.out.println(line);
       writer.write(line);
       writer.newLine();
    }
    reader.close();
    writer.close();
```

I know I may parse the whole html source in another moment and replace all references, but doesn't sound as a good choice. So, is there a way to download the WHOLE content?

Comment: If you can download the HTML file, Why don't you read that HTML text for internal links. Those Internal links that you find, you can download.

Comment: How? Internal links are relative paths, I don't have access to them.

Comment: the relative path is joined to the URL path on process, so you can build the full path using the relative. If Firefox can download it you can.   lets say you have URL www.site.com ,in it relative path /images/123.jpg.  you can get it by: www.site.com/images/123.jpg.